# C++: Iterate using enum type

Tags: c++, for-loop, enums

I have these codes:

```
for (i = 0; i <= WND_WRL; i++) {
   syslog(LOG_ERR, "TESTE i=%d WND_WRL=%d", i,WND_WRL);
}

for (i = 0; i <= WND_WRL; i++) {
   syslog(LOG_ERR, "OnScrDsp for i=%d WND_WRL=%d", i,WND_WRL);
   m_pWnd[i] = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
   assert(m_pWnd[i]);
}
```

The first for is only to explain my problem. The second is really my problem.

The source of second code can be found here:
https://github.com/HuayraLinux/intel-classmate-function-keys/blob/master/OnScrDsp.cpp

The problem:

WND_WRL variable came from

```
typedef enum {
    WND_BRG,
    WND_DSP,
    WND_WRL,
} WND_ID;
```

struct.

In first code I can see i iterate until 2 (0,1,2) and WND_WRL will be always 2. The problem is in second code: even WND_WRL ever print 2 value, that for will iterate i until receive SIGV signal (11) and break my application (here it stop with i=384). I can understand why 384, I am not concerned about that.

What I do not understand is why the same condition provide different ways. If I change WND_WRL to number 2, I get correct code and correct app execution.

My first idea is the block of the second for maybe change WND_WRL value, but isn't happened.

I can understand if may be this code is writing in wrong memory position, but I always see WND_WRL with 2 value.

**SOLUTION :**

Change expression "i <=WND_WRL" to "i < WND_WRL" because m_pWnd size. It explain SIGV, but not explain why for continue until receive SIGV even if 2<=2 condition matches. Overriding memory we know can destroy a lot of things, but constants and code are read-only stack memory region, so access m_pWnd[3] and others i++ not explain why for does not stop.

Comment: How is `m_pWnd` declared? Are you going outside the bounds of the array?

Comment: @FranciscoPanisKaseker add this information to the question, not in a comment. (p.s: if removing optimization flags "fixes" your issue, it sounds like you have UB in your code)

Comment: @Thomas yes, because I received SIGV (signal 11). You can see m_pWnd declaration at github (better than paste here).

Comment: Disabling optimization is not solving overindexing an array but rather hiding the problem. Overindexing cause random crash, and with optimization you just increase the chance. Please fix the overindexing correctly.

Comment: Agree with you. We already saw that here at the same time you sent the fix. Thanks for all. I will updated main thread. Now I only want to know what I wrote in your post below :)

Answer (score 3):

Variable `m_pWnd` is defined in your source code as an array of pointers, with a size of 2, so valid index is 0 or 1.

```
GtkWidget *m_pWnd[WND_WRL];
```

But your loop goes `i <= WND_WRL`, so `i=2` case will crash

```
m_pWnd[i] = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_POPUP);
```

Comment: I agree with you. I can fix this changing <= to < in second for. But now my question is: if source code is protected in memory stack and I can not change that (I think), why access m_pWnd[2] can destroy that for (second code)? WND_WRL always print 2 and what I saw is that force continue until receive SIGV.

Comment: value of m_pWnd[2] is unknown, _most probably_ is pointing to m_pScr, so maybe it's changed somewhere else, I have no overview on the whole system, but overriding memory is like Russian Roulette. WND_WRL is always 2 because it is a compile time constant, value of it can not be changed run time.

Comment: Understood and I agree with Russian Roulette. But something is missing here. The question is why for continue iterate if condition matches (2<=2). As WND_WRL is 2 and can not be changed in run time, we can say the same thing about for code. If I have my code protected in stack memory and I can not write there (read-only space), my for continue doing things (even condition matches) until receive SIGV from kernel.

Comment: I see only one explanation: loop variable `i` got overwritten, hard to tell how/why. Turning off optimization hides the issue because then `m_pScr` is overwritten, but with optimization on, I guess the `m_pWnd` array has a copy on stack for some reason and right after that copy lies `int i` as the first and only local variable. If you want to further investigate, you can play with adding new local variable before `i` (just make sure it's used - so not optimized out) or better to check disassembly of the compiled code.

Comment: or you can add something like this: `printf("&m_pWnd[i] = %p, &m_pScr = %p, &i = %p, i = %d\n", &m_pWnd[i], &m_pScr, &i, i);` to your for loop. I tried with clang, but the optimized code does not overwrite `i`...

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answer in case you satisfied and have no more questions. Thanks